# How to limit the number of words in datalist?

Tags: c#, asp.net, cpu-word, datalist

I have 200 words in description column but I want to display only 100 words in Label in Datalist.

```
SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from tbitem", ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cn"].ConnectionString);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    adp.Fill(ds);
    DataList1.DataSource = ds;
    DataList1.DataBind();
```

In HTML

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server">           
            <ItemTemplate>
                <b>Name: </b> <%#Eval("itemnam") %><br />
                   <b>Description: </b> 
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("itemdescription") %>'></asp:Label>  <br /><br />
            </ItemTemplate>               
        </asp:DataList>
```

And the Description is

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Viverra justo nec ultrices dui. At varius vel pharetra vel turpis nunc eget lorem dolor. Iaculis at erat pellentesque adipiscing commodo elit at imperdiet. Arcu non odio euismod lacinia at quis risus. Quam adipiscing vitae proin sagittis nisl. Consectetur lorem donec massa sapien faucibus et molestie. Mattis vulputate enim nulla aliquet porttitor lacus luctus accumsan. Quis imperdiet massa tincidunt nunc. Risus sed vulputate odio ut enim blandit volutpat. Nunc id cursus metus aliquam eleifend. Tristique magna sit amet purus gravida quis blandit turpis. Sollicitudin tempor id eu nisl nunc. Enim eu turpis egestas pretium aenean pharetra magna. Nibh nisl condimentum id venenatis. Duis at tellus at urna condimentum mattis pellentesque.
```

What will be the code behind it?

Comment: So why not to try to get only 100 letters from sql query? by using like this => `SELECT SUBSTRING(itemdescription, 0, 100) AS itemdescription FROM tbitem` ?

Comment: This will show 100 characters not words..@er-sho

Comment: So how your words separated from each other? Could you please provide sample input?

Comment: First 100 words only @Crowcoder

Comment: Yes, I got it after you showed the sample but your question could be (and was) interpreted differently.

Comment: Could you solve it?

Comment: Basically, you need to alter your datasource before binding it. Your could transform your data table into a viewmodel that does a `String.Split` on that column or you could add a column to the datatable, loop over the rows setting its value to the result of the first 100 tokens of a split and then bind that column to your datalist instead of the original. I don't have an actual answer worked out, does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be,

You can loop over on rows in data table inside your data set and then only take 100 splited words from column from each row and then make string from spliited word and bind it to the same column

The code was not tested but you can use something like below,

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

adp.Fill(ds);

foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    row["itemdescription"] = string.Join(" ", Convert.ToString(row["itemdescription"]).Split(new char[] { ' ' }).Take(100));
}   

ds.Tables[0].AcceptChanges();

DataList1.DataSource = ds;
DataList1.DataBind();
```

Comment: This is not showing exact 100 words. but 89 words only.

Comment: Ok try to keep only space in split function like => `.Split(new char[] { ' ' })`

Comment: How much comma and dot in your string I think they would be 11 that why its shows 89 words only

Comment: Thanks it Worked. with .Split(new char[] { ' ' }). Thanks a lot.